# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox troubleshooting

Tags: perl, firefox, www-mechanize, mozrepl

I have MozRepl installed in my browser and set to start on startup and accept outside connections.

So my questions are as follows
1) will simply running the code `my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();` launch the firefox browser?

2) I have set MozRepl to accept outside connections however, while firefox is not launched, when my script reaches the code in 1), it tells me `unable to connect, problem connecting to localhost, on port 4242`. I tried to debug by doing `telnet localhost 4242` with firefox browser not launched. It also gives me this error `Could not open connection to the host, on port 4242: Connect failed`.

Should i be expecting this result?

3) Given the difficulties I'm experiencing above, I decided to use system() to launch the browser before creating mechanize::firefox instance. The browser is able to start, however it never reaches the code where mechanize::firefox instance is to be created.

```
#where i manually fire up firefox.
system('"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"'); 

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0});
$mech->get( 'https://192.168.1.23' );
```

What can i do to make sure  firefox browser can be launched yet it will not affect the sequence of the code, such that mechanize::firefox instance can be created to manipulate the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your browser before your test, it is not started automaticaly.

I takes time to start firefox, but system returns instantly after firefox started. I takes some seconds to initialize all of its plugins, etc.

The easiest thing is to wait 30 sec via sleep, or you start a while loop to wait until it is responding.

It is possible that a firewall rule prevent you access mozrepl. The default port is 4242.
check the port via telnet:

```
telnet 192.168.1.23 4242
telnet 127.0.0.1 4242
```

Comment: when i use system/exec to launch firefox, it successfully launches firefox but nothing happens after that, using exec tells me that the the line `my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0});` is unreachable. What can i do to make sure this line can be reached.

Comment: for some reason, my system command does not return after launching firefox